# htaccess redirect search query string with keyword

Tags: php, string, .htaccess, search, redirect

I am struggling with search redirect with handwritten word (not dynamic) but never the same word

I need to redirect this:

```
http://www.example.com/search/results.html?search_in_description=1&keyword=rabbit
```

To this:

```
http://www.example.com/recherche?orderby=position&controller=search&orderway=desc&search_query=rabbit
```

Knowing "rabbit" is just an example, could be any word.

Comment: you should mention what HTTP server you are using for correct answer!

Comment: @wirefram `Knowing "rabbit" is just an example, could be any word.` that is why it's called dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search_in_description=1&keyword=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^search/results.html$ /recherche?orderby=position&controller=search&orderway=desc&search_query=%1 [L,R=301,NE]
```